# PHP insert into MySQL after 30min

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have MySQL table:

[image: table]

and I want to add next row (from script in page) with values:

```
ip:              178.40.12.36
time:            2014-01-22 14:08:04
browser:         Google Chrome
browser_version: 32.0.1700.76
platform:        windows
country:         Slovakia
```

**Question:** How to determine in mysql query to insert only **if last insert** with same identificator (IP+browser+platform) **was 30min ago** ?

My current insert (pseudo code):

```
$exist = SELECT * 
         FROM table 
         WHERE ip = $ip 
         AND browser = $browser 
         AND platform = $platform

if(!$exist) {
    INSERT INTO table ...
}
```

**My Idea:**

```
$exist = SELECT ...
         ... 
         AND time < $time - 30MIN
```

*Note: How to write this in MySQL?*

Comment: Make your `time` criteria such that matching records are *less than* 30 minutes ago. Then, you'll know to add a new record if nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's easy.

```
AND time > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

There are many choices like this for date arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this as indicator:

```
  SELECT 
    COUNT(1) 
  FROM `t` 
  WHERE `ip` = '$ip' 
    AND `browser` = '$browser' 
    AND `platform` = '$platform' 
    AND `time`>NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

-I've replaced `time` with `NOW()` for current time, but you may wish to count from your last `time` value.

It will select records what are newer than 30 minutes, thus, if it's positive, then you don't need to insert new row(s).

Comment: -1 I am counting from your last time, because it is not inserting 30min from visit, but 30 min after last visit

Comment: It's a check. If I've got you correctly, you need to check if such records exist. So, "records newer than 30 min exist" is equal to "records, for which time is greater than current time - 30 min". May be I've missed usage explanation: if that `COUNT` above is positive, then _do not_ insert rows

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter the `SELECT` for the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `Table` ( ... )
SELECT $ip, $time, $browser, $browser_version, $platform, $country
FROM `Other_Table`
WHERE ip = $ip AND browser = $browser AND platform = $platform AND
    time < $time - 30MIN
```

Now, clearly that syntax won't work exactly, but you get the idea. If the `time` isn't `30MIN` or more ago then it will return `0` records to `INSERT`.

This will avoid the need of performing a `COUNT` or `EXISTS` first; it can be done in one statement.